# how can i unlink this child from the parent in blender?

Tags: blender

this is my first time modelling a character in blender.

link to pic: [screenshot](https://app.box.com/s/hs0ubgmrnfxzt14qx802sk0murul43ib)

the rest of the body is complete but now i wanna combine the hands to the arms and as you can see the hands are child to the body. i tried many things which i found on google like pressing U, Alt+P, etc but nothing worked. when i right click and select unlink it says not yet implemented. everything i do to hand is happening to the body too. i want the hand to be a separate entity. pls tell me how can i do that :'<

Comment: Your title is rather disconcerting.

Answer (score 1):

pressing P worked. thanks for your time anyway